# How to make log4j2 print suppressed exceptions?

Tags: log4j2

log.error(someMessage, someException) prints only the stack trace of someException and its causes, but doesn't print suppressed exceptions (although the "standard" printStackTrace() method prints those suppressed).

Is it possible to turn on printing suppressed exceptions in log4j2?

Comment: Please create a Jira issue for Log4j 2 and request this.

Comment: Ok. It's probably fixed in 2.4. It's not yet available in mvn repo...

Comment: Just verified this is resolved as of 2.5.